# Old pc,broken system,erase data

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, fedora

I have an old desktop pc that i'm going to get rid of.
There is 2 partitions on the hdd : a ext4 primary & swap partition .

The bios can only boot the internal HDD or a cd .(It doesn't recognize others media).
The desktop boot the grub2 cli because the fedora system is broken.
I tried to boot on every kernels manually(including rescue),every time the boot is stuck and end by halt the system,just before that,there is this message:

```
dracus : refuse to continue
```

Is there a way to erase the data on my hdd from the grub2 cli ?
( i don't have a live-cd nor cd-rw to write on)

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [Unix.SE], [Apple.SE], or more generally [SU].

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [Darik's Boot and Nuke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darik's_Boot_and_Nuke) aka DBAN.

It automatically deletes the contents of any hard disk that it can detect. This method prevents identity theft before recycling a computer. DBAN is also a commonly used solution to remove viruses and spyware from Microsoft Windows installations.

You can download the `.iso` here: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/dban/dban/dban-2.3.0/dban-2.3.0_i586.iso?r=&ts=1487775316&use_mirror=svwh

Use any disc burning utility to burn an image of the `.iso`. Next, set the computer BIOS or UEFI to make the CD/DVD drive the first bootable device. Restart and it should start wiping all the discs it can recognize.

Comment: where can i find a live-cd of it ?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Grub is not going to offer any way to erase partitions or format partitions. What you need is an fdisk utility. Such a utility will give the ability to erase the offending partitions in the first place, which is what I believe you are looking for. Erasing the partitions will leave the HDD in a state of 'unallocated space', and if you plan on getting rid of this PC, that would give the next user an older PC with an empty HDD to set up as they please.

```
                  Hope this helps Craig
```

Comment: how can i get a fdisk utility to work here, can i access a usb stick by grub2 then launch a fdisk utility in it ?

Comment: several possibilities - LIVE USB or LIVE DVD or thru a windows disk/startup disk. Add some info - these will NOT need grub to access your disk.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is to dismount the HDD and connect it to a working computer, then use the HD management tools in that machine's OS to recreate the partition table (or, if you're more comfortable with this, secure erase the entire drive before doing so).  Once this is done, you can either reinstall (L)Ubuntu on the HDD, or just pass the machine on with a blank HDD.

FWIW, if you download Plop Linux and burn it to CD, its bootloader can allow a boot from USB, even on a computer with BIOS too old to do so.  You could supply that CD and a USB with Lubuntu on it when you pass on the old computer, and someone will get a reasonably usable system from day one.